# Why is this variable not set?

Tags: elisp

When evaluated from a scratch buffer, why does the elisp debugger say that variable "a" is void?

```
(setq a "b")
(insert a)
```

The reported error is:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten to do a <kbd>C-j</kbd>. With it you also
get the feedback with the result of evaluation inserted into the buffer.
I'd also suggest to use `ielm`.

### UPD

Here's the whole sequence, just in case:

1. `emacs -q` - don't want any extra packages to mess up anything
2. <kbd>q</kbd> - you're now in `*scratch*`
3. `(setq a "b")`
4. <kbd>C-j</kbd> - `"b"` should appear automatically
5. `(insert a)`
6. <kbd>C-j</kbd> - `bnil` should appear automatically
7. Done. The value of `a` was inserted, along with `nil`,
   which was the result returned from `insert`.

Comment: I meant, do a C-j on (setq a "b") You should see "b" inserted into the buffer.

Comment: I'm asking how to set a value to a variable and then insert this value by invoking the variable name.

Comment: Zhro: there's nothing wrong with the code. abo-abo is saying that you are obviously only evaluating the second sexp. `C-j` and `C-x C-e` evaluate the *previous* sexp, **not** all preceding sexps.

Comment: In elisp, how do I then store value in a variable, within a larger block of code, and reuse it later?

Comment: Ok.. then how do I execute it as described in my original question?

Comment: I don't want to evaluate each line individually. I want to evaluate the entire file like a script.

Comment: You should phrase your questions much more clearly. It's `eval-buffer` you want.

Comment: `eval-buffer` or `eval-region` (after selecting the sexps to evaluate) or wrap the code (multple sexps) in a `progn` and use `C-x C-e` or `C-j` (if in `*scratch*`).  *Suggestion:* `C-h i`, then choose `Emacs Lisp Intro`, then read this fine introduction to Emacs Lisp.  And I agree with @abo-abo: try a bit harder to express [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325973/a-smarter-alternative-to-delete-window) *clearly* -- you will get better help that way. It's not so much about language (English) as it is about logic (content).