# A smarter alternative to delete-window?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Sometimes I get multiple windows open for the same buffer (or a similar one) and I have to differentiate whether or not the buffer in the window is the same as another before deciding to either kill it or delete the window.

Is there a way in emacs to simply delete a window only if the buffer exists already in another? Ideally I would like the same function to also kill the buffer and the window if it is the only instance of the buffer in a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the behavior I was looking for. Thank you for helping with the basic function layour and logic. Elisp is still very confusing to work with and I appreciate help with getting through the rough spots.

See the code somment which explains the behavior. You should also be able to understand it directly from the source.

I've up-voted your previous answer which includes the bulk of the code I used.

```
;;; Delete the selected window without killing the buffer if the buffer is open
;;; in another; otherwise close the window and its buffer. If called on the
;;; last visible window then the buffer will simply be killed and replaced by
;;; the next available buffer.
(defun delete-window-maybe-kill-buffer ()
  "Delete selected window.
If no other window shows its buffer, kill the buffer too."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((selwin (selected-window))
         (buf (window-buffer selwin)))

    (if (> (length (window-list)) 1)
        (delete-window selwin)
      (unless (get-buffer-window buf 'visible) (kill-buffer buf))
      (kill-buffer buf))))
```

Comment: Your `if` tries to kill the buffer twice: first conditionally, then unconditionally. The `unless` clause goes with the second `kill-buffer`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun delete-extra-windows ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((selwin  (selected-window))
         (buf     (window-buffer selwin)))
    (walk-windows (lambda (ww)
                    (unless (eq ww selwin)
                      (when (eq (window-buffer ww) buf)
                        (delete-window ww))))
                  'NO-MINI 'THIS-FRAME)))
```

Comment: Nice! Why do you define `wins` though, it doesn't look like you use it?

Comment: Good catch. No reason. It should be removed --- I've done that now.

Comment: Can you make this function call kill-buffer-and-window if the selected window has the last instance of the buffer?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  It sounds like you now want to just delete all windows (in all frames?) showing the buffer and kill the buffer too.  If so, that's what `kill-buffer-and-its-windows` does (in library [`misc-cmds.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/misc-cmds.el)).  If that's not what you want, please clarify.  Preferably open a new question for that, so an answer with an example can be provided.  (One cannot format code in a comment.)

Comment: The above code could be revised, as it doesn't completely answer the question.

The function should call delete-window if the buffer of the selected window also exists in another window. Otherwise call kill-buffer-and-its-windows to kill the window AND the buffer.

Comment: Adding another answer, as an example cannot be written in a comment (as I said).

Answer (score 1):

I added [`quit-window`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quitting-Windows.html) (normally bound to <kbd>q</kbd> in non-self-insert - AKA `special` - buffers) 15 years ago to solve a similar problem.
You can try it or its sibling `quit-windows-on`.

Answer (score 1):

Your specification of what you wanted is not clear.  You said "delete a window only if the buffer exists already in another".  That means do *not* delete the window if the buffer does not exist in another window.  Yet you also said "kill the buffer and the window if it is the only instance of the buffer in a window", which contradicts the first requirement.

I guess by "delete a window only if..." you really meant "delete only the window (not also the buffer) if...".

```
(defun delete-window-maybe-kill-buffer ()
  "Delete selected window.
If no other window shows its buffer, kill the buffer too."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((selwin  (selected-window))
         (buf     (window-buffer selwin)))
    (delete-window selwin)
    (unless (get-buffer-window buf 'visible) (kill-buffer buf))))
```

Comment: Reports an error "Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window" when using the function on the last remaining window/buffer. The expected behavior is for the window to delete and the buffer to be killed.

Comment: @Zhro: From the beginning your problem is poorly specified: just what behavior you are asking for. That's still the case for your latest comment. The error you cite is a standard Emacs error that is raised when you try to delete the only window in a frame. Sorry, but if you want better help you will need to specify more rigorously the exact behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Delete only the window (not the buffer) if the same buffer is open in another window; otherwise kill both the buffer its the window.

Comment: That is exactly what the above code does. It unconditionally calls `delete-window`. Then, unless the buffer is shown in some remaining window, it kills the buffer.  It deletes the window, but it does not kill the buffer if the buffer is visible in another window.

Comment: The expected behavior when called on the last remaining window is for it to delete the window and kill the buffer. Everything else is fine.

Comment: To clarify: Delete only the window (not the buffer) if the same buffer is open in another window; otherwise **when called on the last instance of the buffer in a window** kill both the buffer and its window. Currently it reports "Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window" instead of killing the buffer and deleting the last window.

Comment: I don't know how to make this clearer. Please reread my earlier reply about this error message. You **cannot** delete/kill both the buffer and its window if there is no other window in the frame. That's an Emacs limitation: you ***cannot delete the sole window of a frame***. You can, however, delete the frame (which deletes the window) and kill the buffer. Or you can just kill the buffer (which replaces it in the window by another buffer).

Comment: Yes. Simply killing the buffer and replacing it in the window by another frame is the behavior I am looking for. Calling "kill-buffer" on the last remaining instance should do this, I believe.

Comment: 1. You cannot replace a *buffer* by a *frame*, in a *window*. You can kill the buffer without deleting the window. But you said you want to kill the buffer only if it is visible somewhere else. Now you want to kill it even if it is not. Your description keeps changing. Given the info you have already been given, you should be able to code what you *REALLY* want yourself at this point. All the elements are there. You know how to test whether a buffer is visible only in the selected window. You know how to delete a window, and you know how to kill a buffer. To delete a frame, use `delete-frame'.